# Static Analysis Tools For Kotlin Programming Language?

Tags: android, kotlin, static-code-analysis

`PMD,FindBugs,CheckStyle` etc are the most commonly used static code analysis tools for `java`.

I think Android-Lint is the only trusted static analysis tool that exists and can only be used to analyse an android project.

Sonarqube doesn't have a Kotlin plugin yet.I think they are planning to provide this later this year.(i found this information on the below link).

https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/sonarqube-support/3657

Please,Correct me if i'am wrong ?

Comment: I think that Idea IDE Lint inspector is the way to go

Comment: This is a very helpful and a question in need,Please remove the hold.

Comment: @Amalp check this https://medium.com/@danielvivek2006/code-styling-for-kotlin-fa7a8291c254

Answer (score 5):

IntelliJ does a great job (and I think I've heard it can be accessed via command line). Other than that, I know of Ktlint (https://github.com/shyiko/ktlint) and Detekt (https://github.com/arturbosch/detekt). I've worked with neither of them, but they seem sensible alternatives. At least Detekt also has Sonarqube integration.